# How to fix RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo due to Resources$NotFoundException: used for activityTheme on Android 11+ devices

Tags: android, android-activity, view, android-drawable, embedded-resource

We are getting a crash occurring only on Android 11 and lower devices.

stack trace -

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{..SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable:drawable/background_splash with resource ID #0x7f0800cb


Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable:drawable/background_splash with resource ID #0x7f0800cb



Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/background_splash.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800cb
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:898)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.originalLoadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:679)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:586)
       at android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(MiuiResourcesImpl.java:307)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:932)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1007)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:982)


Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08090e
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValueForDensity(ResourcesImpl.java:248)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getValueForDensity(Resources.java:1385)
       at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(BitmapDrawable.java:819)
```

[image]

**Its giving resource not found for - **res/drawable/background_splash.xml**, which is clearly available.**

[image]

background_splash.xml is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>

    <item android:bottom="128dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|center"
        android:drawable="@drawable/splash_logo_p4b_new">
    </item>

    <item
        android:gravity="bottom|fill_horizontal"
        android:drawable="@drawable/blue_bottom_strip">
    </item>

</layer-list>.
```

**blue_bottom_strip and splash_logo_p4b_new** are images of png formats.

and how this vector is used as a background in the Activity theme like this.

```
    <style name="ThemeSplashScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_white</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>.
```

Use of this theme in Android Manifest -

```
   <activity
        android:name=".splash.SplashActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeSplashScreen"
        android:exported="true">
```

It could be because of https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen, looking into it.

**Could you help me how to analyse the root cause here? Thanks you for your time and attention.**

**EDIT - 28 Marhch 2023**

This crash is fixed in Android 12+ devices after we applied [Migrate your existing splash screen implementation to Android 12 and higher](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate), we did have some issues regarding the branding image dimension related issue
[Migration of exisitng splashScreen to Android 12 + is giving distorted splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75368672/migration-of-exisitng-splashscreen-to-android-12-is-giving-distorted-splash).

So Now I have left with this issue for only in Android 11 and 11- devices.
Why does it say that resource can't be found?

Comment: What kind of drawable is `background_splash.xml`?

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidWasser, for looking into this.
I have put the XML in the question itself now.
It's a layers-list drawable.

Comment: What kind of drawables are `blue_bottom_strip` and `splash_logo_p4b_new`?

Comment: they are both png @DavidWasser

Comment: Yes, you probably need to go back to using the `<bitmap>` method.

Comment: actually, when observing again, I see, the crash still happened when <Bitmap were still nested inside the item. @DavidWasser

Comment: Same crash or something different??

Comment: @DavidWasser yaa same crash, And I forgot to check one other important thing, how the vector was used, and I've put it in the question.
Actually this vector is used as a background in splash screen activity theme.

Comment: We are getting the same crash, wondering if it's due to the layer-list drawable as we are using that too. Did you find a solution @VikasPandey ?

Comment: After we did Splash screen migration it didn't happen for Android 12 and + devices, because it's not using this drawable just the middle icon, and we have to provide the bottom branding image as a separate image in them only.

Thanks for sharing the info that you are too getting the same crash and using layer-list, yes I think I should some other way and see that it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. We'll have a look at the Android 12 splash screen and see if that resolves our issue. It's a shame that the official splash screen API and customizability is not that great.

Comment: and I did one more thing, In the layer-list the 2 <Bitmap, I had moved them into the <Item tag only, Because some other team in out org it did solved similar issue.
Once I get confirmation that after this change the crash doesn't happen, will update here.
<Bitmpap was preferred in the official doc, though after the change ( moving the icon from <bitmap to <Item and seting it as drawable ) has the same look and feel.

Comment: Hello @VikasPandey any update on that issue ?
Did the transition from <bitmap to <item solved your issue ? 
I'm facing the same issue, also using layerlist, on some Android 11- devices