# Migration of exisitng splashScreen to Android 12 + is giving distorted splash

Tags: android, android-theme, android-12, android-splashscreen

We are trying to migrate (because of a crash, that seem related to this - [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75206320/how-to-fix-runtimeexception-unable-to-start-activity-componentinfo-due-to-resou) another question for my crash.

Our existing Splash-Screen which also serves as routing.

Previously we used a full screen vector as a theme of splash screen, after following the documentation -

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate#prevent_the_custom_activity_from_displaying

and updated the theme like this -

```
<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
</style>
```

`background_splash` is the drawable image that we want to have in full screen there. Its not working?

Splash screen is looking distorted, the `windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon` is cropped and put into a small circle in the center.

Anyone has idea how to achieve this correctly? Thank you for your time!

**Is it possible to provide a full screen drawable to splash in accordance with the new splash API for android 12+ with backward compatibility?**

Answer (score 0):

Searched for a solution working with Android-12 as well as with older versions and didn't like to create multiple resolution images. Android-12 changed the behaviour of the splash screen ([migration guide](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate)) but this resulted in a well sized icon either for Android-12 or for earlier versions, but not for both.

Finally I ended up with a trick, to add two splash screen xml files, one for version 12 and higher, the other for all other versions. Give the item (parent of the image) a size in dp, and the bitmap a gravity="fill". The size differs for both splash_screen xml, I don't know if there is an official solution to this problem.

*resources/values/styles.xml*

```
<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
  <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#387aa8</item>
  <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
  <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/MainTheme</item>
</style>
```

*resources/drawable/splash_screen.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:width="224dp" android:height="224dp" android:gravity="center">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/silent_notes_256"
            android:gravity="fill"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

*resources/drawable-v31/splash_screen.xml (Android-12 and higher)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:width="128dp" android:height="128dp" android:gravity="center">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/silent_notes_256"
            android:gravity="fill"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

While I did tests with different resolutions, I don't know whether this works for all screen size/resolution combinations.